# Can't figure out how to solve matrix equation Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, parametric

I tried googling how to solve this matrix through RREF and parametric variables but failed to find something that works similarly to try and solve myself.

A is a 2x3 matrix with the values going [ 2 -1 -1 : 1 -2  2 ]
(imagine the set after the colon to be under the first set)

x is [x_1, x_2, x_3] but obviously a column instead of a row and for lack of subscript key I just used "_#" to denote the same thing.

0 is a 2 row x 1 column matrix with two 0's.

To start, I wrote out the matrix's into 2 equations.

2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 0

x_1 - 2x_2 + 2x_3 = 0

Then I turned it into a simplified coefficient matrix.
[ 2 -1 -1 0: 1 -2  2 0] (with the second set of numbers past the colon under the first set)

Afterward, I reduced it into RREF form to get:

[ 1 0 (-4/3) 0 : 0 1 (-5/3) 0 ] (with the second set of numbers past the colon under the first set)

Once I got this, I turned the matrix back to these equations:

X_1 - (4/3)X_3 = 0

X_2 - (5/3)X_3 = 0

So then I set X_1 = (4/3)X_3 and X_2 = (5/3)X_3. I then tried setting X_3 to t to try and see if I could finagle an answer by solving for 't'. So far, my answers have been wrong every time in comparison to the answer my book gives. Can someone tell me if I messed up somewhere? I deduced it would have to be from my matrix reduction but I did it over a few times in different ways to make sure but I still can't seem to get the answer...

Comment: Note that $x=0$ works and that's not interesting. What's interesting is trying to find *all* solutions. In that case you will necessarily have some free variables in your answer, if that's what is bothering you?

Comment: what is the answer in the book?

Comment: x_1 = t
x_2 = 5/4t
x_3 = 3/4t

I guess I am looking for all solutions as I know the trivial solution works; I get really similar answers but my x_1 is not t, my x_3 is t.

Comment: @Charlatan Are you sure that's the answer? It does not tell you what $x_3$ could be

Comment: @Mark I pressed enter by mistake earlier

Comment: In the future, please format your mathematical expressions using MathJax, most especially the matrices. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @amd I appreciate this; I was wondering if I'd have to go copy and paste from some table; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, indeed by the augmented matrix for the system and by row operation we obtain

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&   -1&   -1&  0\\
      1&   -2&  2&  0
    \end{array}\right]\to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&   -1&   -1&  0\\
      0&   -3&  5&  0
    \end{array}\right]\to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      6&   0&   -8&  0\\
      0&   -3&  5&  0
    \end{array}\right]$$

from which we obtain

- $x_1=\frac43 x_3$
- $x_2=\frac 53 x_3$

that means we have a free parameter and by $x_3=t$ the genral solution is

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t\left(\frac43,\frac53,1\right)$$

which is equivalent to

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t\left(4,5,3\right)$$

Comment: the book gives the answer as x_1 = t; I suspect I may of done something wrong but this is the answer set I get.

Comment: This implies the book solution is wrong. In particular if $x_1 = x_2$, there is no way $Ax = 0$

Comment: @Charlatan I believe you have a fundamental misunderstanding on the meaning of a solution. It does not make sense to talk about $x_1 = t$ as a solution. A solution to the problem must be a statement about all the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and how they relate to one another

Comment: I am using Larson's Elementary Linear Algebra 8th Ed; the question is from section 2.1 question 37. Although it could be the book, I feel like the book could be onto something I am not seeing.

Comment: Yes there must be simply a typo in teh solution or in the given matrix.

Comment: "In Exercise 37 and 38, solve the matrix equation Ax=0". 
X_1 = t, X_2 = 5/4t, X_3 = 3/4t is the complete answer incase you haven't seen my edit on the comment earlier; I pressed enter before I finished writing out my answer by mistake.

Comment: @Charlatan Then that's correc indeed $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t\left(1,\frac54,\frac34\right)$ is equivalent to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t\left(4,5,3\right)$

Comment: @gimusi I see now that they divide the terms by 4 to make X_1 = t; thank you all for assisting me with this problem.

Comment: @Charlatan You are welcome. Yes indeed if $x$ is a solution to $Ax=0$ of course any multiple $kx$ is a solution indeed $A(kx)=k(Ax)=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The general method for solving a linear equation 
$$Ax=b$$
is to utilize the Moore-Penrose inverse $A^+$ and the associated nullspace projector $$P=(I-A^+A)$$

With these two matrices, the general solution can be written as
$$x=A^+b + Py$$
where the vector $y$ is completely arbitrary.

Applied to the current problem this technique yields 
$$\eqalign{
&A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-1\\1&-2&2\end{bmatrix},\quad
&A^+=\frac{1}{50}\begin{bmatrix}\;\;16&\;\;\;2\\\;-5&-10\\-13&\;\;14\end{bmatrix},\quad
P=\frac{1}{50}\begin{bmatrix}16&20&12\\20&25&15\\12&15&9\end{bmatrix} \\ 
&
b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
p=\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\\3\end{bmatrix}
&\implies P=\frac{\;\;pp^T}{50},\quad
x=0+\frac{p(p^Ty)}{50}
 = \lambda p 
 = \lambda\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\\3\end{bmatrix} 
\\
}$$

Comment: Informative, but how does it help the OP find the error in _his_ computation?

Comment: it does strike me interested; I haven't learned this method before but it looks rather useful... 

How do you find A+ and P?

Comment: The definition  $P=(I-A^+A)$ holds in all cases. In this particular case, the matrix rows have _full rank_ and therefore $\;A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$. In general, $A^+$ can be hard to calculate manually, but most languages (Matlab, Julia, Python) provide a function.